How can I mapToObj for two IntStreams?
Say, I have two method which each returns an IntStream.
static IntStream getKeySizeStream() {
    return IntStream.of(
            128,
            192,
            256
    );
}

static IntStream getBlockSizeStream() {
    return IntStream.of(
            128
    );
}

I want to define a new method which returns a stream of combination of these two streams.
And a way that I found is this.
static Stream<Arguments> getKeySizeAndBlockSizeArgumentsStream() {
    return getKeySizeStream().boxed().flatMap(ks -> {
        return getBlockSizeStream()
                .mapToObj(bs -> Arguments.of(ks, bs));
    });
}

How can I do without the .boxed().map() part? Can I do that?

I found an answer.
static Stream<Arguments> getKeySizeAndBlockSizeArgumentsStream2() {
    return getKeySizeStream().mapToObj(ks -> {
        return getBlockSizeStream().mapToObj(bs -> Arguments.of(ks, bs));
    }).flatMap(Function.identity());
}



Why do you use the verbose syntax for the first lambda expression? Use the same compact syntax as for the second, return getKeySizeStream().mapToObj(ks -> getBlockSizeStream().mapToObj(bs -> Arguments.of(ks, bs))) .flatMap(Function.identity());
